# Changing bootsplash

Tags: release-freya, themes, boot, plymouth

I've been attempting to change the bootsplash. I've followed the instructions I've found for ubuntu 14.04 thinking they would work since it's based on that distro. I created my own theme which I'll paste the code below. Are there any special instructions since elementary OS is very heavily rebuilt?

dell.plymouth:

```
[Plymouth Theme]
Name=dell
Description=Dell Bootsplash
ModuleName=script

[script]
ImageDir=/lib/plymouth/themes/dell
ScriptFile=/lib/plymouth/themes/dell/dell.script
```

dell.script:

```
wallpaper_image = Image(“wallpaper.png”);
screen_width = Window.GetWidth();
screen_height = Window.GetHeight();
resized_wallpaper_image = wallpaper_image.Scale(screen_width,screen_height);
wallpaper_sprite = Sprite(resized_wallpaper_image);
wallpaper_sprite.SetZ(-100);
```

[image: 1280 width]

Comment: Have you looked at Plymouth Manager? http://ubuntuguide.net/plymouth-manager-gui-tool-to-change-initial-splash-screen-themes-in-ubuntu

Comment: yeah, just posted the code and image I've used.

Answer (score 3):

In order to use your theme you need to add and set an alternative for the default plymouth theme, and update the initrd image.

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /lib/plymouth/themes/default.plymouth default.plymouth /lib/plymouth/themes/dell/dell.plymouth 75
sudo update-alternatives --set default.plymouth /lib/plymouth/themes/dell/dell.plymouth
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

You can also test your theme without rebooting by using `plymouthd` and `plymouth`.

```
sudo apt-get install plymouth-x11
sudo plymouthd
sudo plymouth show-splash
```

**Edit:** Here's the slightly modified `dell.script` that I used for testing:

```
Window.SetBackgroundTopColor(0.91, 0.92, 0.91);
Window.SetBackgroundBottomColor(0.80, 0.80, 0.80);

screen.width = Window.GetWidth();
screen.height = Window.GetHeight();

dell.image = Image("wallpaper.png");
dell.width = dell.image.GetWidth();
dell.height = dell.image.GetHeight();

if(dell.width < dell.height) {
  dell.ratio = screen.height / dell.height;
  dell.x = Math.Abs(screen.width - (dell.width * dell.ratio)) / 2;
  dell.y = 0;
} else {
  dell.ratio = screen.width / dell.width;
  dell.x = 0;
  dell.y = Math.Abs(screen.height - (dell.height * dell.ratio)) / 2;
}

dell.scaled = dell.image.Scale(dell.width * dell.ratio, dell.height * dell.ratio);
dell.sprite = Sprite(dell.scaled);
dell.sprite.SetX(dell.x);
dell.sprite.SetY(dell.y);
```

Comment: I've done all that and everything looks as if it went well but when the splash comes up, it's just a black screen. What are the requirements for the wallpaper? Format? Size? Resolution? Bit depth?

Comment: I'm not sure about wallpaper requirements. I tested all of this in a VM and it came up fine (although it wasn't scaled properly). You might want to try another theme that is known to work to determine whether its a problem with your theme or a problem with changing the default theme.